# Parent doesn't take height of children on safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari, positioning

Well my structure is :

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="slide">
        <div class="slider-top">
            <img src="..." />
            <div class="cont-text"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS for it :

```
#slide {
  display:block;
}
#slider {
  width:100% !important;
  display:block;
  min-width:960px; 
  position:relative;
}
#slider .slider-top {
  width:100% !important;
  height:auto !important;
  display:block;     
  overflow:hidden;
  min-width:960px;
}
#slider .slider-top img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  max-height:857px;
  min-width:960px; 
  margin-top:-4px;
  display:block;
}
```

So this is my slider made with Jquery Cycle 1, its a slider that must go full width and stop resizing the image if the display is less then 960px;

I have the next problem the slider works great on Chrome,Mozzila,Ie 10/9/8 but on safari the Slider and Slide ID take no height so the element position wrong + the next container in the DOM goes under the slider.

If you can help me make it work i would aprecciate

UPDATE : made a fiddle of it : http://jsfiddle.net/Kv4ce/1/
The problem on the website is that the navigation ( the numbers ) go top because they see no height on the parent, plus the slider covers up the next Dom element

Update : forgot to tell that my site acts strange , if i enter the website address directly in the bar it loads perfect the problem appears only on refresh

Comment: can you make a fiddle - jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Quick note on the edit, you were missing an end-quote on id="slide", make sure your original gets fixed.

Comment: I updated the post with the fiddle Tilwin Joy8